# How do I transfer my World of Warships Blitz ships to World of Warships?

Tags: world-of-warships

I can’t even transfer... anyone got an answer?

I just want to transfer because I have the aircraft carrier Independence on mobile but on the Mac version I only have Langley.

Comment: You can't transfer, and you can't even transfer? That sounds problematic indeed. Can you give more details what exactly you mean by 'transfer'? Have you looked up possible solutions?

Answer (score 2):

According to a couple of items on [the official World of Warship Blitz FAQ](https://support.wgmobile.net/hc/en-us/categories/360000174534-Account-Management), it may not be possible. While they look similar, they are treated as two different games.

You can, however, move between servers and platforms.

### Can I move my items from one server to another?

https://support.wgmobile.net/hc/en-us/articles/360002010297-Can-I-move-my-items-from-one-server-to-another-

"Unfortunately, you cannot move the whole account between servers. However, we can move some of your premium content to a new account of yours.

If you want to transfer content from one server to another, please submit a support ticket. Make sure to include the following information:

- Player IDs and servers of both accounts you would like to transfer between
- List of items you wish to transfer
- Reason for transferring
- The name of Internet Service Provider that you use when playing WoWs Blitz"

Nevertheless, I'd still try contacting their support to see if they can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Answer:
You Can't!

"World of Warships" and  "World of Warship Blitz" are two different games, that are played differently and are marketed as two different Games by Wargaming.

An example is "World of Tanks" and "World of Tanks Blitz". Both can be played on PC but are considered two entire different games in the eyes of Wargaming.

Comment: Something that confirm this issue is about difference between tech tree (I never played Wows Blitz and rarely played Wows), but for the case of WoT, there is some  tanks unavailable on Blitz version and also on the *normal* (1st guess are CW tank rewards or WT Auf E100 - which is still on Blitz). As all of us know how WG works, both games (Blitz and *normal*) would have same issues